# Javascript variable in function changes global variable

Tags: javascript, scope, clause

i have a huge problem figuring out scopes and clauses. I want to have a tmp variable, that i remove one element from. But the global variable should stay intact. This is what iv´e come up with. This;

```
var test = ['test', 'huhu'];

function foo(bar) {

    var tmpTest = test;
    var index = tmpTest.indexOf(bar);

    if (index > -1) {
        tmpTest.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(tmpTest);
}

foo('huhu');
console.log(test);
```

Should produce this;

```
test
test, huhu
```

But produces this;

```
test
test
```

I also tried to make `var tmpTest = new Array(test);` But this stops the splicing from working. I guess what´s happening is that when i set `tmpTest = test`, `tmpTest` just becomes a reference to the original `test` variable? How can i come around this?

Comment: Objects (including arrays) are passed around using their references! So both `tmpTest` and `test` are referencing the same array (space in memory)! You have to copy the array using another way like this: `var tmpTest = test.slice();`!

Comment: FWIW, the problem has nothing to do with scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are objects. Objects in JavaScript are manipulated by references. Assigning a reference does not involve making a copy of the object; it's merely a copy of the reference. Thus, your `tmpTest` variable is just another reference to the same object.

There's a simple way to make a copy of an array:

```
  var tmpTest = test.slice(0);
```

That constructs a new array with all the same values as the original.

The `Array()` constructor can be invoked with one or more arguments, but the arguments are not interpreted as being an array to make a copy of. If it's invoked with one number argument, that's interpreted as an initial `.length` value for the array. More than one argument creates a new array with those values.